# JavaScript variable not evaluating in Jekyll include

Tags: javascript, jekyll, leaflet

I'm building a web-map layout for Jekyll based on [a blog post](http://katydecorah.com/code/2014/01/26/mapbox-for-jekyll-posts/), although I'm using Leaflet.js instead of Mapbox.js.

In the front matter of a post, markers are defined as a list of arrays. The format is as follows:

`[ "lng, lat", "Popup Content", "Font-awesome Icon", "Color of Marker"]`

Two markers might look like this:

`markers:
 - ["-84.312, 33.845", "Regional Office", "home", "red"]
 - ["-84.393, 33.753", "Federal Building", "building", "blue"]`

I take the options from the marker and add them to the GeoJSON representation as properties.  In order to use [Leaflet.awesome-markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) each item must be represented as a Marker Layer instead of a GeoJSON Layer.  Luckily the GeoJSON Layer provides a method to [convert each point to a Marker Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer).

It seems that even though I have access to the feature (and therefore the features properties), I can't get the variable `feature.properties.icon` to evaluate.  After Jekyll works it's magic and produces the static HTML files I see that the icon property is still set to "feature.properties.icon" instead of the value of that variable.

`console.log(feature.properties.icon)` evaluates to `"home"` as expected in this case.

**Post Front-Matter:**

```
---
title: "This is an Example of a Map-Centric Post"
layout: post
tags:
 - Map

map: leaflet
center: "33.733784, -84.389369"
zoom: 9
map-background: terrain
markers: # [ Coordinates, Popup Content, Font-Awesome Icon, Color]
 - ["-84.312, 33.845", "Office", "home", "red"]
 - ["-84.393, 33.753", "Federal Building", "building", "blue"]

---
```

**leaflet.html include:**

```
<script>
var toner = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 20
}),
terrain = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 18
}),
map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [{{page.map-background}}]
}).setView([ {{page.center}} ], {{page.zoom}} );

map.touchZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();

{% if page.markers %}
    var markers = [{
        "type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features":[
            {% for marker in page.markers %}
                {
                    "type":"Feature",
                    "properties":{
                        "popup": "{{marker[1]}}",
                        "icon": "{{marker[2]}}",
                        "color": "{{marker[3]}}"
                    },
                    "geometry":{
                        "type":"Point",
                        "coordinates":[ {{ marker[0] }} ]
                    }
                }{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    }];

L.geoJson(markers, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        console.log(feature.properties.icon) // This works!
        var mapMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
            icon: feature.properties.icon, // This doesn't work
            prefix: 'fa',
            markerColor: feature.properties.color
        });
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: mapMarker
        });
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popup);
    }
    }).addTo(map);

    {% else %}
        markerLayer.clearLayers();
    {% endif %}

</script>
```

Developer Tools:
[image]

**Edit:**
Switching to bracket notation `icon: feature['properties']['icon']` worked only on the index.html page, and not the blog-post page.

Comment: the error comes from this `L.AwesomeMarkers.icon` line I highly suspect. Did you specify the js file for *AwesomeMarkers*?

Comment: Yes, `leaflet.awesome-markers.js` is conditionally loaded just before the block of javascript above.  If I replace `feature.properties.icon` with the string "home" the plugin works fine.

Comment: oops, then try with bracket notation like `feature['properties']['icon']`

Comment: Really, really strange.  This fixed my issue on the index.html page where I rattle of the last 5 blog posts.  When I click on the post to go to the post-specific page I get the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined` despite using the exact same javascript to process the page.

Comment: glad that helped. for blog specific pages, open the console and type `markers` and let me know the output

Comment: It looks like leaflet.awesome-markers.js is only being loaded on the index page for some reason.  I should be able to iron it out from here; thanks for your help